# Create reel images in diferent pictureboxes WinForm c#

Tags: winforms

I have a c# Windows Form project and it function fine, but too slow. I have a list with all images path, with a timer I look for each respective list element and asign the image to respective picturebox. As I told you it works fine but I need that it runs faster. This is the code that timer_tick() runs.

```
private void PresentarImagen()
    {
        var Foto1 = lstFotos.Where(o => o.PhotoTime == horaActual && o.Camara ==        pb1Cam).FirstOrDefault();
        var Foto2 = lstFotos.Where(o => o.PhotoTime == horaActual && o.Camara == pb2Cam).FirstOrDefault();
        var Foto3 = lstFotos.Where(o => o.PhotoTime == horaActual && o.Camara == pb3Cam).FirstOrDefault();

        if (pbFotoC1.Image != null) { pbFotoC1.Image.Dispose(); pbFotoC1.Image = null; }
        if (pbFotoC2.Image != null) { pbFotoC2.Image.Dispose(); pbFotoC2.Image = null; }
        if (pbFotoC3.Image != null) { pbFotoC3.Image.Dispose(); pbFotoC3.Image = null; }

        if (Foto1 != null)
        {
            pbFotoC1.Image = Image.FromFile(Foto1.PhotoPath);
            if (bRotarImg) pbFotoC1.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
            pbFotoC1.Tag = Foto1.PhotoPath;
        }

        if (Foto2 != null)
        {
            pbFotoC2.Image = Image.FromFile(Foto2.PhotoPath);
            if (bRotarImg) pbFotoC2.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
            pbFotoC2.Tag = Foto2.PhotoPath;
        }

        if (Foto3 != null)
        {
            pbFotoC3.Image = Image.FromFile(Foto3.PhotoPath);
            if (bRotarImg) pbFotoC3.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
            pbFotoC3.Tag = Foto3.PhotoPath;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is *faster*, in practice? What is the Timer's Interval set to? -- If you load the image as, e.g.: `var img = Image.FromStream(new FileStream([Image Path], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), false, false);` and you draw the image yourself, it could probably take 1/3 of the time (or less, if you rotate the image efficiently). `GdipImageRotateFlip()` (the GDI+ function called when you use `Image.RotateFlip()`) is quite slow. Most of the time is quite probably spent there

Comment: Thanks a lot Jimi, My timer interval is set to 100 ms. I want to looks like a video. If I show only 1 image it runs really fast but with 3 images takes almost 2 seconds. it works better with Image.FromStream. Sorry about this but i don´t know how to rotate the image with GdipImageRotateFlip(). Could you give me an example please!! Thanks.

Comment: I did it whit GDI and the same result. With ImageList runs amazing but I have to show thousands of images and ImageList get "out of memory". Thanks I will find out more options.